# Ignore a command's return status in a systemd service

Tags: systemd, exit-status

I have the following problem, I am working a script that creates a fifo device file, but I want to return true even if the file exists already. The following snippet is trying to create fifos from the `||` and `/bin/true` as well. How can I tell the `mkfifo` cmd that the last argument is `X`?

```
$ /usr/bin/mkfifo /dev/fifofile || /bin/true
```

Running this in a systemd service:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkfifo /dev/fifofile || /bin/true
```

```
Apr 29 08:39:40  mkfifo[27275]: /usr/bin/mkfifo: cannot create fifo '/dev/fifofile': File exists
Apr 29 08:39:40  mkfifo[27275]: /usr/bin/mkfifo: cannot create fifo '||': File exists
Apr 29 08:39:40  mkfifo[27275]: /usr/bin/mkfifo: cannot create fifo '/bin/true': File exists
```

Trying to change the `ExecStartPre` to `ExecStartPre=(/usr/bin/mkfifo /dev/fifofile) || /bin/true` gives the following error:

```
 Executable path is not absolute: (/usr/bin/mkfifo /dev/gpsfifo) || /bin/true
```

Comment: Just a comment to say that a named pipe is most definitely not a device file. Why are you creating it in `/dev`?  Why don't you just `rm -f fifo; mkfifo fifo`?  Also, why are you using absolute paths to standard utilities?

Comment: @Kusalananda because I want to emulate a serial port, but this is not the scope of this question

Comment: The correct way to ignore the exit status in systemd it [to prefix the command with a `-`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=).

Comment: The correct way of emulating a serial port is `openpty()` or `posix_openpt()`  which will give you a `/dev/pts/xx` device that actually acts like a serial port - you can do all the `tcgetattr`  and  `tcsetattr` things on it that you need to do on a real serial port.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkfifo /dev/fifofile || /bin/true
```

That's fine as a shell command line, but systemd doesn't run `ExecStartPre` commands and such through the shell. (I'm not sure if the paths of `mkfifo` and `true` are needed)

The [documentation says](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) that:

> Each command line is unquoted using the rules described in "Quoting" section in systemd.syntax(5). The first item becomes the command to execute, and the subsequent items the arguments.
>
> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection using `<`, `<<`, `>`, and `>>`, pipes using `|`, running programs in the background using `&`, and *other elements of shell syntax are not supported*.

But as quotes should work, you could be able to explicitly run a shell with something like

```
ExecStartPre=sh -c 'mkfifo /dev/fifofile || true'.
```

That should not be necessary, however, since systemd has a special syntax for ignoring errors.

> If the executable path is prefixed with `-`, an exit code of the command normally considered a failure (i.e. non-zero exit status or abnormal exit due to signal) is recorded, but has no further effect and is considered equivalent to success.

So, just

```
ExecStartPre=-mkfifo /dev/fifofile
```

should do.

I'm not sure about the inevitable error message, though, as the note about redirections only mentions `>`, and not `2>`. But you could also do this to remove the file first and then recreate it:

```
ExecStartPre=-rm -f /dev/fifofile
ExecStartPre=-mkfifo /dev/fifofile
```

Of course that would also nuke any other file with the same name.

If you want to guard against that, you could do something like this:

```
ExecStartPre=sh -c '[ -p /dev/fifofile ] || mkfifo /dev/fifofile'
```

That should quit silently if the pipe already exists, but would let `mkfifo` give an error if the file exists and isn't already a pipe.

There might also be a more "correct" place to put the fifo file.

Comment: Why the `-` prefix on `rm`? `-f` already makes it not error if `/dev/fifofile` doesn't exist. Although it would probably still error out if `/dev/fifofile` existed, but couldn't be deleted. Which would probably be a fine indication of something wonky going on (I'm not familiar enough with fifos to tell).